# I want SQL query for select multiple columns into one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one single table and in that table there are three columns company1, company2, company3.

Below is my table data :

```
Company1    Company2    Company3
ABC     
Test1       Test3   Test5
Test2       Test4   Test6           
testing     testing2
```

And I want to combine these columns into single column with serial number like below :

```
SrNo    CompanyName
1       ABC     
2       Test1           
3       Test2      
4       testing 
5       Test3
6       Test4
7       testing2    
8       Test5
9       Test6
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the desired result is with `UNION ALL` of a `SELECT` query for each company column. Assign the serial number value in order by source column and company name using `ROW_NUMBER` in the outer `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO #Company(Company1, Company2, Company3)
VALUES
    ('ABC', NULL, NULL)     
    ,('Test1', 'Test3', 'Test5')
    ,('Test2', 'Test4', 'Test6')           
    ,('testing', 'testing2', NULL);

SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SourceColumn, CompanyName) AS SrNo
    , CompanyName
FROM (
    SELECT 1, Company1
    FROM #Company
    WHERE Company1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, Company2
    FROM #Company
    WHERE Company2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, Company3
    FROM #Company
    WHERE Company3 IS NOT NULL
    ) AS Companies(SourceColumn, CompanyName)
ORDER BY SrNo;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked using UNPIVOT for these types of operations.  Assuming you have some sort of ID column on the source table, this also works.

```
DECLARE @Company TABLE 
    (
    PKID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , Company1 NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    , Company2 NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    , Company3 NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @Company 
    (Company1, Company2, Company3)
VALUES
    ('ABC', NULL, NULL)     
    ,('Test1', 'Test3', 'Test5')
    ,('Test2', 'Test4', 'Test6')           
    ,('testing', 'testing2', NULL);


SELECT SrNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PKID, CompanySrcCol)
    , CompanyName 
FROM @Company AS C
    UNPIVOT (CompanyName FOR CompanySrcCol IN (Company1, Company2, Company3)) AS unpvt
ORDER BY PKID
    , CompanySrcCol
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union of three queries like something like this

```
SELECT 1 AS tableNro, Company1 AS CompanyName
  FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS tableNro, Company2
  FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS tableNro, Company3
  FROM yourTable
```

To get the serial number you could use row_number like something like this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (x.tablenro, CompanyName)) AS SrNo, x.CompanyName
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS tableNro, Company1 AS CompanyName
      FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS tableNro, Company2
      FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS tableNro, Company3
      FROM yourTable
) x
```